# How to translate "technology"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How should one translate "technology"?

E.g. in the [introduction to a beginner's programming tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/#introduction):

> We hope that we'll be able to make you love technology as much as we do!

ReVo doesn't seem to have a translation, and Google translate suggests "teknologio". Though I wonder whether other terms are more appropriate when referring more to the abstract concept (all that technical stuff surrounding us and whatever powers them) rather than the scientific discipline.

Maybe any of these? (Made up on the spot by composing appropriate-seeming affixes to ["teĥnik/o"](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/te%C4%A5niko)):

- teĥnik[**aĵ**](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/-a%C4%B5)o
- teĥnik[**ec**](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/-ec)o (Though I think this would instead be "technicity" / "technicality".)
- teĥnik**i**o
- teĥnik**ik**o (Though this would probably again refer specifically to science, I guess? Also, is the "-ik-ik-" redundant or is the first "ik" part of the root?)
- teĥnik[**um**](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/um)o (Well, that can probably kinda mean anything, can't it?)

Comment: Specifically in translating the text linked in the question, while I don't know the intention of the authors of the English original, I think I should aim for a "technology" meaning that is neither limited to the scientific methods (of technique) nor limited to its products. (So _-**logi**o_ and _-**aĵ**o_ don't seem to be the right choices.) It should be more than a single technique (so not just _teĥniko_), maybe encompassing several, but it should be a singular word (thus not _teĥnikoj_). Therefore, I think I'll go for _teĥnik**ar**o_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Technology* often is a hyperbole (exaggeration) for *technique* (*technical mean*). The ReVo definition is apt.

Hence possible are:

- `teĥnikoj`
- `teĥnologio`(hyperbolic usage in E-o)
- `teĥnikaro`

Comment: What do you mean by hyperbole / exaggeration? Hype buzzwords like "blockchain technology"? That's not the meaning I'm after I think.

Comment: Thanks for the "teĥnik**ar**o" suggestion!

Comment: While in English _-logy_ is used in a hyperbolic way as Joop stated, in Esperanto _-logio_ refers to study, science, so _teknologio_ is a study of some technique. [_Tekniko_](http://vortaro.net/#tekniko) is according to PIV "tuto de la metodoj k procedoj, uzataj por plenumi verkon aŭ produkti objekton" and thus _teknikaĵo_ a single detail.

Answer (score 3):

I think *teĥnologio*/*teknologio* works fine here. See the [definition in ReVo](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/tehxnologi.html#tehxnologi.0o):

> Tuto de formalaj metodoj kaj rimedoj dediĉitaj al iu celo kaj maŝine aŭ industrie realigeblaj

with this example sentence:

> Memkompreneble la komisiito de Monato tre konvinke kunĵuris pri satelita taŭgeco, kvankam li, honeste dirate, tute ne posedas satelitricevilon, sed sendispute tiu teĥnologio vere estas liverinta al ni perfektan Esperanto-programon en la tuta Eŭropo.

That seems to have the meaning you want. Maybe you could add *aĵ* to indicate that you're talking about a concrete result of the scientific methods, so *teĥnologiaĵo*. This of course depends on whether the sentence you provide means to refer to the scientific methods or the results thereof. I am not getting any hits for `te[kĥ]nologiaĵ` in Tekstaro though.